# PyQt use QT remote objects

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a server and a client written in c++ using QT remote objects:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtremoteobjects-index.html

I would like to create a test server in python the c++ client can connect to.
Is there any way to use an .rep file from python to create and host a qt remote object (the cpp client can connect to)?

Here is an example client:
main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <rep_myserver_replica.h>
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QRemoteObjectNode repNode;
    QSharedPointer<MyRemoteObjectReplica> mo;
    if (!repNode.connectToNode(QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:6112")))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    mo.reset(repNode.acquire<MyRemoteObjectReplica>());
    auto f = [&]()
    {
        auto f2 = [](QString s) { std::cout << "Answer arrived: " << s.toStdString() << std::endl; };
        if (!QObject::connect(mo.get(),&MyRemoteObjectReplica::magicConvertResponse,f2))
        {
            std::cerr << "Unable to connect to magicCOnvertResponse()" << std::endl;
        }
        mo->magicConvert("ALMA");
    };
    if (!mo->isInitialized())
    {
        if (!QObject::connect(mo.get(),&MyRemoteObjectReplica::initialized,f ))
        {
            std::cerr << "Unable to connect to initialized()" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        f();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

myserver.rep:

```
class MyRemoteObject
{
    SLOT(magicConvert(QString text))
    SIGNAL(magicConvertResponse(QString text))
};
```

Comment: Currently this submodule is not available in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently(April 2021) I'm trying to achieve same, Python Server/Source and C++ Client/Replica. I didn't use any rep, eventually it's possible register `QObject`'s child as source:

```py
# MyClass.py

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot

class MyClass(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot(int, name="someMethod")
    def someMethod(self, value):
        print("someMethod called with value " + str(value))
```

```py
# main.py

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtRemoteObjects import QRemoteObjectHost

from MyClass import MyClass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    api = MyClass()
    remoteHost = QRemoteObjectHost(QUrl("local:class"))
    remoteHost.enableRemoting(api, "MyClass")
    return app.exec()
```